# How private is private mode in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, cookies

I am using a **private** window in Firefox (78.0.2).
I navigate to https://www.nfz-messe.com and accept the cookies.

After I close Firefox and restart Firefox, when I navigate to the same site, there is no question on cookies. So somehow it is stored across sessions.

So, I do not feel private anymore.

Anybody know why this is and how to prevent it?

Comment: I figure they use a combination of IP address and browser to recognize the same user. Once I change my IP address the cookie consent comes back again.
see: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9037/can-web-sites-detect-whether-you-are-using-private-browsing-mode/211766

Answer (score 1):

## Private mode of firefox

**What it does**

- Doesn't save browsing history and bookmarks
- The downloads are not shown in the download history (But saved to the computer)
- Doesn't keep the cookies

**What it does not**

- Doesn't offer you full anonymity, such as ToR does by hiding your IP address and tracking information completely
- What you visit might be visible if you are in your workplace or school (This should not be an issue at home).

So I think using different Firefox profiles is a better solution. You can go to about:profiles and manage your profiles. [More help here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-remove-switch-firefox-profiles).

Also you can use a live Linux CD/USB which has Firefox pre-installed like Ubuntu, Kali, Linux mint etc. None using this computer can get a trace of you.

Comment: Don't forget that your ISP has access to what you visit (at least in the US), so using a VPN or, like you suggested ToR in a VM or Live CD is probably the only way to fully guarantee anonymity.

Comment: Thanks @MarsNebulaSoup for the info

Comment: Posting the FAQ is not an answer to my question. It does not explain how the website recognizes me.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that with an add-on like uMatrix, the private mode completely ignores this add-on.

Therefore, I just auto-delete my history (or manually by history › delete most recent history) since I still want to use privacy-related plug-ins while browsing.

Comment: I know that you can enable add-ons in incognito mode in chrome, so maybe it can be done in Firefox too.

Comment: Thanks, I searched for that and it is indeed possible: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/extensions-private-browsing